# ProgressBar not showing up

Tags: android

**Edit: I realized that the code posted below works flawlessly in Nexus 6 (shamu) and Galaxy Tab A, both with android 7.0! And it does not show on Moto G5 Plus (android 7.0).**

It's a simple question. My ProgressBar won't show up. At frist I was trying directly at my LoginActivity, but I wasn't having success. Things that i tried:

1. Put ProgressBar directly inside the layout
2. Put ProgressBar inside a layout
3. Set ProgressBar propriety indeterminate to true
4. Set the visibility of progressbar and parent layout to VISIBLE
5. Create a separated .xml file and call a Dialog (in this case, if I put a textview inside the text will appear but the progressbar won't)
6. Change the proprieties layout_width and layout_height
7. A combination of all the steps above
8. Last I tryed to create this simple blank activity showing only the progress bar...

activity_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="context_name_here">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

test.java:

```
package package_name_here;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }
}
```

What's the problem? I suspect that is something about the resources... the image of the default progressbar or version of android... 
any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.
The Animator duration scale have to be ON at Developer options from device:
Developer options -> Developer duration scale -> 1x (ON)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's one of Android's weird stuff

Answer (score 1):

Try with hard-coded dimension for the width and height for ProgressBar, also check your Colors that might be the same as activity default,  also check by removing the style attribute once, or try with a different style for ProgressBar.

Comment: I had already tried this when I was testing the progressbar in my app... but I checked again in the code a posted here and no success... thanks anyway

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? @Eduardo Fernando

Comment: @DMur I did. The problem was solved by the accepted answer. Look for my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private TextView textView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        // Start long running operation in a background thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    // Update the progress bar and display the
                    //current value in the text view
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Define XML:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:progress="1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_cyclic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Your code works great, but the second progressbar isn't showing up... I tested in other devices and everything worked fine... even my example code.. So I thing it is a problem with the default progressbar, thanks anyway

Comment: Make acepted answer @EduardoFernando

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare the progress dialog

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
```

then in your `onCreate`

```
 progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    progressBar= new ProgressBar(test.this);

progressBar.show();
```

to dismiss the dialog or cancel it you can use

`progressBar.cancel();` or `progressBar.dismiss();`

Comment: I wished to do it directly in the layout, without use a Dialog... but I have new information about the problem... I edited the question post